# SQL sum rows in union

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, union

I'm trying to SUM two rows obtained from differente SQL queries in UNION, is this possible?
All I can achieve is the two separate rows but I can't SUM them, DB engine keeps me telling that there's an error in the syntax near the *) FROM (the part next to the SUM)...

Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT COUNT(*) as cntclients                                                                                               
   FROM                                                                                                                      
   (SELECT DISTINCT clientkey AS clients                                                                                     
      FROM <table>
     WHERE <conditions...>)                                                                                                                 
   ) AS clients                                                                                                              
) cntclients

UNION

(SELECT SUM(occurrences) AS cntclientsad                                                    
   FROM <table2>
   WHERE <conditions...>                                     
)
```

This throws me for example:

```
cntclients
----------
901
50
```

Adding a SELECT SUM(*) FROM instead of the SELECT * FROM in the first line, and surrounding the two queries with parentheses just throws me the mentioned error...

I would like

```
cntclients <- or whatever name...
----------
951
```

Any ideas how this sum should work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't actually need to use a `UNION` for this - you can just add them together manually:

```
SELECT a.countKey + b.sumOccur as total
FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISINCT clientkey) as countKey
      FROM <table>
      WHERE <conditions>) as a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(occurrences) as sumOccur
            FROM <table2>
            WHERE <conditions>) as b
```

Comment: Instead of `JOIN ... ON 1=1` you could use `CROSS JOIN` (without `ON`).

Comment: @ypercube - Thanks - I don't need a true cartesian product often, so I forget about it.

Answer (score 8):

```
select SUM(cntcol)
from
(
    select count(*) as cntcol from sometables
    union all
    select SUM(occurrances) as cntcol from somemoretables
) ctquery
```

Comment: Don't you need a `GROUP BY` to use `SUM()` ?

Comment: Nope.  If you want to sum all rows why would you need any kind of grouping?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick with the `UNION` you can write it this way:

```
SELECT sum(c.cntclients) as Totalcntclients 
FROM
(

   SELECT COUNT(*) as cntclients                                                                                               
   FROM                                                                                                                      
   (SELECT DISTINCT clientkey AS clients                                                                                     
      FROM <table>
     WHERE <conditions...>                                                                                                                
   ) AS clients                                                                                                              

  UNION

  SELECT SUM(occurrences) AS cntclientsad                                                    
   FROM <table2>
   WHERE <conditions...>                                     

) c
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use:

```
SELECT 
    ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT clientkey) as countKey
      FROM <table>
      WHERE <conditions>
    ) 
  +
    ( SELECT SUM(occurrences) as sumOccur
      FROM <table2>
      WHERE <conditions>
    ) 
  AS total
```

Comment: Got similiar problem, and Thanks for simplicity of Yours answer I could write a proper query. Thanks. Still, I wonder, why when i replace ) + ( for union in query dosn't work proper? Nothing in docs gave me a clue.

Comment: If you do that replace ment you have a subquery like: `(SELECT cnt ... UNION SELECT ...)` which is a table with 1 column, 2 rows. You can make it work with `SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM (SELECT cnt ... UNION SELECT ...) AS g`. My query above works without additional aggregate (SUM) because the subquery returns a table with 1 column, 1 row. And you can put these subqueries in the Select list.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I took for this was to create a View for the UNION query.  Then you can simply use

```
SELECT SUM(cntclients) FROM <view>
```